# Two measures that agree on a $\pi$-system but not equal on the generated $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\mu$ and $ \nu$ be two measures on $(\mathbb{X},\sigma(\mathscr{C}))$ where $\mathscr{C}$ is a $\pi$-system such that $\mu$ and $ \nu$ agree on $\mathscr{C}$. Now let $(\mathbb{X},\sigma(\mathscr{C}))$  be $\sigma$-finite w.r.t. both $\mu$ and $ \nu$. It can be shown that if $\mathscr{C}$ contains sets $\{C_n:C_n\subset C_{n+1},n\geq 1,\bigcup_n C_n=\mathbb{X}\}$ and $\mu(C_n)=\nu(C_n)<\infty$ then $\mu=\nu$.

In Cohn's *Measure Theory*, he asked for a counterexample when the condition that $\mathscr{C}$ contains sets $\{C_n:C_n\subset C_{n+1},n\geq 1,\bigcup_n C_n=\mathbb{X}\}$ and $\mu(C_n)=\nu(C_n)<\infty$ is replaced by mere $\sigma$-finiteness. I could not produce a counterexample. Please help.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something from the definitions, but can we set $\mathbb X=\{1,2\}$, $\mathcal C=\{\{1\}\}$, and choose $\mu(\{1\})=\nu(\{1\})$ but $\mu(\{2\})\neq\nu(\{2\})$?

Comment: Your example is a nice one but in the book, he mentioned to replace the finiteness of the measures by $\sigma$-finiteness. So I am assuming that both of the measures will be infinite and the $\sigma$-algebra will be $\sigma$-finite with respect to these measures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Example:** $\Bbb X=[0,1]$, $\mathscr C:=\{(a,b]: 0<a\le b\le 1\}$. Then $\mathscr C$ is a $\pi$-system generating the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr B([0,1])$. Define $\mu(B)=\int_B x^{-1}\,dx$ and $\nu(B)=\mu(B)+1_{B}(0)$ for $B\in\mathscr B$. Then $\mu$ and $\nu$ are $\sigma$-finite measures on $\mathscr B$  that agree on $\mathscr C$, but clearly $\mu\not=\nu$.

Comment: Thank you. It is a nice example.